# WSO2 ESB array with single element json to json conversion brackets missing

Tags: json, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 esb 4.9 and created a proxy with payloadFactory element and call it with REST to start my BPMN process, but the problem is esb cannot convert single element json array , and esb drops json array's brackets. here is my proxy :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


   <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="InformationIncome"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
                {
               "processDefinitionId":"myProcess:6:25188",
               "variables": [
                  {
                    "name":"text",
                    "value":"$1"
                  }
               ]
            } 
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.text"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <header name="Authorization"
                 scope="transport"
                 expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('admin:admin'))"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <store messageStore="InformationIncomeMS"/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

And Here is the content of my request from soapUI :

```
{
    "text" : "Hello"
}
```

And I found out my json becomes like this after payloadFactory:

```
{
    "processDefinitionId":"myProcess:6:25188",
    "variables": {
        {
            "name":"text",
            "value":"Hello"
        }
    }  
}
```

it seems esb json converter drops brackets of arrays with single element. Any ideas?

Comment: This issue exists also using WSO2DSS server, are there any solutions?

Comment: I tried to write a model binder in my .net microservices to transform json to a valid format for single elemented arrays and integer to string conversion and I know this is not correct because two modules are coupled with each other in this way, I think the main problem exists in jsonStreamBuilder in wso2 ESB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DilshaniS said : 
Looks like this is a bug in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 and reported an jira [this link](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4750)

Answer (score 1):

I tested above scenario with Postman, and it works properly. Please find steps as follows;

- Add proxy and remove message store. (Because adding null message to message store giving following error)

  [2016-07-11 13:46:53,291] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
  java.lang.Error: Error: could not match input
  at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.zzScanError(JsonScanner.java:530)
  at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.yylex(JsonScanner.java:941)
  at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.nextSymbol(JsonScanner.java:310)
  at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.next(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:149)
  at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.peek(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:272)
  at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:129)
  at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:132)
  at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.hasNext(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:446)
  at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.next(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:456)
  at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:88)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:336)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator._getFirstChild(OMNavigator.java:199)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.updateNextNode(OMNavigator.java:140)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.getNext(OMNavigator.java:112)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.updateNextNode(SwitchingWrapper.java:1113)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.(SwitchingWrapper.java:235)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMStAXWrapper.(OMStAXWrapper.java:74)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMStAXWrapper.(OMStAXWrapper.java:52)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMContainerHelper.getXMLStreamReader(OMContainerHelper.java:51)
  at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getXMLStreamReader(OMElementImpl.java
- Use Postman and invoke proxy service with "POST" command

Add json content in to body

[image: Snapshot of POSTMAN]

- Send it. ESB will print the message correctly with brackets.

Comment: The log mediator prints the json message with brackets correctly but when the message goes through the message broker and message processor sends it to another pass through proxy, in the last proxy log mediator prints the message without brackets, here is the flow :
Proxy1 -> Message store -> Message Processor -> Proxy2 -> myEndPoint(.Net api), json prints correctly in Proxy1 but it's corrupted without brackets in Proxy2. also this happens when I send single elemented array, if I send it as a 2 elemented array brackets won't drop.

Comment: This won't happen if i change payload Variables array like this : 
"variables": [
                  {
                    "name":"text",
                    "value":"$1"
                  },
                  {
                    "name":"text2",
                    "value":"$1"
                  }
               ]

Comment: Can you attach your request ? The way you send the json content

Comment: I send it just like your postman request with Content-Type = "application/json" instead of xml

Comment: When ESB receiving json message from MB, it will pop up an error. How you going to solve that ? or please provide whole configuration, that you used to receive jms message from wso2 MB.

Comment: I receive jms messages from message broker with integration of jms message store and scheduled forwarding message processor with basic interval, max delivery attempts, drop on max delivery configurations. just this

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 and reported an jira :https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4750

Comment: Anyway, this was given as a patch for production customers and you may this feature with next ESB release (5.0.0)